# X509Certificate2.Export fails with "Keyset does not exist" in console application

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I do not have deep knowledge of how storing and working with certificates from within code should be done "properly", so will use rather "simple language" to explain my problem.

I have certificate, which was generated by code (using Bouncy Castle), actually [this is the code](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/12/how-to-create-x509certificate2.html) which was used to create certificate.

1. The code returns `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate` certificate.
2. This certificate object is then converted into `byte[]` array, using `Pkcs12Store` (Bouncy Castle class) and saved into `c:\temp\cert.pfx` file.

Now I need to load the certificate from file into code, update Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) (which is not correct) on the private key and write the certificate and private key to new `cert2.pfx` file.

**UPDATE**

On the first run my console app would went through, and all other runs I will get error "**Keyset does not exist**" on this line: `certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password")`

NOTES:

The code is running in Console application and folder `c:\temp\` got full permissions for `Everyone`.

Most topics related to "Keyset does not exist" are related to permissions (e.g. Network Service does not have right access), I suppose this is not my case.

I haven't imported `cert.pfx` into windows store (Personal nor Local Machine) and prefer not to import it.

This is code sample:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFileBytes, "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var privKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

// will be needed later
var exported = privKey.ToXmlString(true);

// change CSP
var cspParams = new CspParameters()
{
    ProviderType = 24,
    ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
};

var rule = new CryptoKeyAccessRule("everyone", CryptoKeyRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity = new CryptoKeySecurity();
cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);

// create new PrivateKey from CspParameters and exported privkey
var newPrivKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
newPrivKey.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
newPrivKey.FromXmlString(exported);

// Assign edited private key back
certificate.PrivateKey = newPrivKey;

// export as PKCS#12/PFX
var bytes = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password");

File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\cert2.pfx", bytes);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think merely replacing the private key is enough to make a valid certificate.

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but have no idea, how to update Cryptographic Service Provider on Private Key to correct one and keep the certificate valid. Not sure if this is even possible, but would be extremely handy to make it work somehow, because of many integrations we have in our system.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @mimo?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I did solve this by workaround. I used command line tool `openssl` to update incorrect CSP of certificate. This is sample: `openssl pkcs12 -in C:\temp\cert.pfx -out C:\temp\cert.pem -password pass:password -passout pass:password` and re-export certificate with corrext CSP: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in C:\temp\cert.pem -out C:\temp\cert2.pfx -CSP "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -passin pass:password -passout pass:password`

Comment: I wanted to achieve it by code, but was unable to do so because of this error "Keyset does not exist". I think it occurred, because I was exporting certificate directly to file and not via some `Store`.

Comment: Thank you @mimo you are a life saver, this was exactly my issue, changing the CSP did the trick and now I am able to read the PrivateKey in my console application.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well as using the Export-PfxCertificate cmdlet (it gave a similar error). Running the powershell window as admin resolved the problem.